# How to change the default command to open shells in the MobileTerminal Cydia package

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, jailbreak, ios

I am using MobileTerminal on iOS 7, and want to know how to change the default shell from sh: to bash:. I assume I would need to change the login command for this, but how would I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function of the shell set for the user in /etc/passwd (/etc/master.passwd).  Normally you can change this via the chsh command, but iOS7 doesn't have this command. so you need to edit /etc/passwd and /etc/master.passwd (as root) and change the shell for the user mobile to /bin/bash.

So it should look like:

```
mobile:*:501:501:Mobile User:/var/mobile:/bin/bash
```

after changing from:

```
mobile:*:501:501:Mobile User:/var/mobile:/bin/sh
```

Note: in the master.passwd file the '*' will be your encrypted password.

Comment: Thanks, also, is that password the lock screen password, or the passwd used in the passwd shell command. They are two different values, stored in different places as far as I can tell. Also, iFile worked wonderfully for this! I recommend others trying this use iFile.

Comment: The lockscreen password is separate from the user (shell) password.

Comment: Type (not really) `echo $AWESOME` and bash should return `bash: error: Awesomeness of this file was to much to process, the only information gathered was that the owner of the file was user 'MERM'`

Comment: Also, would this work for other shells, ie Z Shell?

Comment: As long as it is a valid shell.  Also it must be listed in /etc/shells for it to work.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that the config in `/etc/master.passwd` or `/etc/passwd` are not honored by Dropbear. You need to have OpenSSH installed and running alongside or instead of Dropbear.